# Use of SCNMorpher produces undesired flat polygon rendering in SceneKit

Tags: scenekit

I am using SCNMorpher in iOS SceneKit to morph between different facial expressions on a 3D face model exported as a DAE file from Blender. The morphing itself works fine.

Before I first call `setWeight:forTargetAtIndex:` on the morpher, the model is rendered smoothly, as desired.

But as soon as I make that call, all the polygon edges become visible, which is very unattractive. It's the same difference as switching from 'smooth' to 'flat' rendering in Blender itself.

Images follow: first the smooth rendering, pre-morph, then the flat rendering, post-morph.

[image: Smooth rendering, pre-morph]
[image: Flat rendering, post-morph]

I'm using the Lambert lighting model (though the others are affected just the same), and litPerPixel is true for every material of every target geometry.

I'm not clear if this is a known/deliberate limitation of SCNMorpher, a bug, or something I'm doing wrong. I wonder whether the morph is somehow screwing up the vertex normal data which would normally be used for smooth rendering.

Any light anyone could shed would be much appreciated. (I guess a possible workaround might be to do the morphing manually by interpolating all the vertex and normal vectors to form a new geometry, but I imagine this will be unpleasantly slow).

The relevant part of the code is as follows:

```
faceNode.geometry = faces.rootNode.childNodeWithName("neutral", recursively: true)!.geometry
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(faceNode)

var morphs: [SCNGeometry] = []

let moods: [String] = "mood1 mood2".componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
for mood in moods {
  let moodFace = faces.rootNode.childNodeWithName(mood, recursively: true)!.geometry!
  morphs.append(moodFace)
}

let morpher = SCNMorpher()
morpher.targets = morphs

faceNode.morpher = morpher
morpher.setWeight(0.5, forTargetAtIndex: 0)
```

Comment: Possibly there's something wrong with how the normals are built into the mesh in Blender, but that's a bit outside my bailiwick. (Try fudging with whatever export options Blender gives you, or using other tools to play with the vertex buffer layout. [Model I/O](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ModelIO/Reference/ModelIO_Framework/index.html) in iOS 9 / OS X 10.11 might help on that front.) Or it might be a Scenekit bug — you can always [file it](http://bugreport.apple.com) and find out.

Comment: Thanks, I've filed it.

Answer (score 7):

Just ran into this problem as well. 
You need to set unifiesNormals to true on the morpher.

```
let morpher = SCNMorpher()
morpher.targets = morphs
morpher.unifiesNormals = true
faceNode.morpher = morpher
```

Comment: Huh — that looks very likely to solve the problem. Thanks. But that property has only been available since iOS 11, so it wasn't an answer back when I asked the question.

I filed a bug report on this at the time, and Apple claimed to be unable to reproduce the issue, even when I supplied a minimal test case as an Xcode project. But good to see they finally addressed it anyway!

Answer (score 0):

An update on the possible workaround I mentioned above: morphing manually by interpolating all the vertex and normal vectors to form a new geometry.

This does in fact work surprisingly well, using Accelerate/vDSP to do the interpolation.

My use case is a bit less general than what is provided by SCNMorpher — I only need to morph between two models at any one time. And the following code achieves this (at a rate of around 30fps, for geometries of around 40,000 vertices, on my iPhone 6):

```
// .h

@property (nonatomic) size_t morphBufferSize;
@property (nonatomic) float* morphBuffer;

// .m (note: we assume floats not doubles by using vDSP_vintb rather than vDSP_vintbD)

- (SCNGeometry*)morphGeometry:(SCNGeometry*)g1 toGeometry:(SCNGeometry*)g2 withWeight:(float)weight {
  SCNGeometrySource* v1 = [g1 geometrySourcesForSemantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex].firstObject;
  SCNGeometrySource* n1 = [g1 geometrySourcesForSemantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticNormal].firstObject;
  SCNGeometrySource* v2 = [g2 geometrySourcesForSemantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex].firstObject;
  SCNGeometrySource* n2 = [g2 geometrySourcesForSemantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticNormal].firstObject;

  vDSP_Length len = v1.data.length;
  vDSP_Length numFloats = len / sizeof(float);

  if (_morphBufferSize < len) {
    _morphBuffer = realloc(_morphBuffer, len);
    _morphBufferSize = len;
  }

  vDSP_vintb(v1.data.bytes, 1,
             v2.data.bytes, 1,
             &weight,
             _morphBuffer, 1,
             numFloats);

  SCNGeometrySource* v3 = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:_morphBuffer length:len freeWhenDone:NO]
                                                           semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex
                                                        vectorCount:v1.vectorCount
                                                    floatComponents:v1.floatComponents
                                                componentsPerVector:v1.componentsPerVector
                                                  bytesPerComponent:v1.bytesPerComponent
                                                         dataOffset:v1.dataOffset
                                                         dataStride:v1.dataStride];

  vDSP_vintb(n1.data.bytes, 1,
             n2.data.bytes, 1,
             &weight,
             _morphBuffer, 1,
             numFloats);

  SCNGeometrySource* n3  = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:_morphBuffer length:len freeWhenDone:NO]
                                                            semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticNormal
                                                         vectorCount:n1.vectorCount
                                                     floatComponents:n1.floatComponents
                                                 componentsPerVector:n1.componentsPerVector
                                                   bytesPerComponent:n1.bytesPerComponent
                                                          dataOffset:n1.dataOffset
                                                          dataStride:n1.dataStride];

  NSMutableArray* elements = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:g1.geometryElementCount];
  for (NSInteger i = 0, len = g1.geometryElementCount; i < len; i ++) [elements addObject:[g1 geometryElementAtIndex:i]];

  SCNGeometry* g3 = [SCNGeometry geometryWithSources:@[v3, n3] elements:elements];
  return g3;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    free(_morphBuffer);
}
```

Comment: This crashes for me on the second vDSP_vintb(n1.data.bytes, 1,

Answer (score 0):

As Ray McClure said, `unifiesNormals` will work fine because morpher will recompute normals of vertex when target is applied.

Smooth shade will happen when averaging normal of vertex with all adjacent faces. In this situation, render engine render edge by interpolating color for adjacent faces and it looks like faces meet become more 'smooth'.

Why your face model look like blocky is because morpher target of face model has non-smooth normals of vertices on mesh(Or there are not normals information of vertices).

Recompute normals is expansive, so to save performance you may want to export a model with smooth normals.

If you add smooth normals to morpher target using ModelI/O, promblem should go away.

```
SCNGeometry* soomthGeoUsingModelIO(SCNGeometry *geo){
    MDLMesh *mesh = [MDLMesh meshWithSCNGeometry:geo];
    MDLMesh *newMesh = [MDLMesh newSubdividedMesh:mesh submeshIndex:0 subdivisionLevels:0];
    //creaseThreshold is the cos value of MAX crease angle you can tolerate
    [newMesh addNormalsWithAttributeNamed:@"normals" creaseThreshold:0];
    SCNGeometry *flatGeo = [SCNGeometry geometryWithMDLMesh:newMesh];
    return flatGeo;
}
```